# Rolle's theorem: Show that there is a sequence $(a_{n})$ such that $\forall n \geq 1$, $f^{(n)}(a_{n}) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, rolles-theorem

Let $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ such that $f(0) = \underset{+\infty}{\lim} f$.

Show that there is a sequence $(a_{n})$ such that $\forall n \geq 1$, $f^{(n)}(a_{n}) = 0$.

I get the idea for n = 1, but after that, i can’t really find the answer ...

Thank you

Comment: take $f(x) = e^{-x}$, so there is something missing

Comment: @Physor Presumably what is missing is that $\lim_{+\infty}f$ means $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$. It's supposed to equal $f(0)$, which is not the case for your example.

Comment: @Physor: The limit in $\infty$ of $f$ isn’t $f(0)$...

Comment: OK, thanks for clarification

Comment: What does $f(0) = \underset{+\infty}{\lim} f$ mean?

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear, but as Arthur said, $\underset{+\infty}{\lim}f = \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume for the sake of contradiction that the statement is false. Because of OP’s post, there exists some $n \geq 2$ minimal such that $f^{(n)}$ has no root. Then we can assume it is non-negative. As $f^{(n-1)}$ vanishes and is increasing, there is a real number $y$ such that $f^{(n-1)}(y) > 0$.

It follows, by Taylor with integral remainder, as $f^{(n)} \geq 0$, that for $x \geq y$, $f(x) \geq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{f^{(k)}(y)}{k!}(x-y)^k}$. But the RHS goes to infinity as $y$ goes to infinity, which contradicts the assumption.

Comment: Why can't it happen $f^{k}(y) \lt 0$ for $k\lt (n-1)$ ?

Comment: What??? How do you know that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series is nonzero? When you take $n \ge 2$ to be the minimal $n$ such that $f^{(n)}$ doesn't vanish, how do you know $n$ exists? For instance, for $f(x) = 3$ (a constant function satisfying all the hypotheses), the set of $n \ge 2$ such that $f^{(n)}$ doesn't vanish is empty, hence does not have a minimum. And where is your construction of the sequence $(a_n)$?  What does it mean that a function "vanishes"? That it has a root? That it's constantly zero? I can't construct a meaning that makes this answer make sense to me.

Comment: Very clear indeed, thank you for your help ! About the previous comments: Mindlack assumes such a n exists, gets a contradiction, therefore all the derivatives have a root. And user710290, it seems to be possible, but this is not a problem ...

Comment: @user710290: I don’t care about that, that’s not the leading term of the Taylor polynomial.

Comment: @John Hughes: I’m using the Taylor formula with integral remainder. If $f^{(n)}$ vanishes (by that I mean “has a root”) for all $n$, then the result is proved.

Comment: @Mindlack  Ok but how do you conclude that the polynomial goes to infinity if you don't care about the positivity of the coefficients of powers of $(x-y)$ ?

Comment: @user710290: I care about the positivity of the *leading* coefficient of the polynomial. Said leading coefficient is $f^{(n-1)}(y)/(n-1)!$, which is positive by definition of $y$.

Comment: @Mindlack  Right , thanks for the clarification .

Comment: @JohnHughes . (1). The summation in the A is not an infinite series. It has a fixed number ($n$) of terms. (2). We suppose for argument's sake that $n$ exists and show this implies $1=0$ in order to prove that $n$ cannot exist. (3). "$f$ vanishes" and "$f $ has a root" mean $\exists x\, (f(x)=0).$ (4). We prove $\forall n\in \Bbb Z^+\, \exists a_n\,(f^{(n)}(a_n)=0),$ so there is a sequence $(a_n)_n.$